# C2DM: where does C2DMReceiver get instantiated?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I'm trying to develop an android application which uses c2dm services. I've read many tutorials and had a look to the chrometophone example. Seems to be an easy task, but still I can't manage to make things work. The last guide I followed is this one:
http://www.johnhawthorn.com/2010/12/android-cloud-to-device-messaging-1/. I really can't understand if I need to create an instance of the class C2DMReceiver or it will be created automatically when the c2dm service will call one of the functions declared in the class, e.g. onRegistered().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C2DMReceiver` is a `Service`. You never create your own instances of services.

Some of the Google helper code (`C2DMBaseReceiver`) not only provides the superclass for `C2DMReceiver`, but also arranges to call `startService()` on `C2DMBaseReceiver` as needed based on C2DM events.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for clearing up my mind! So, everything should be just correct, only maybe it's still too early and the google account (http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/android/c2dm/signup.html) has not been activated yet. This might be why the onRegistered method from the class C2DMReceiver gets never called.

Comment: @singingAtom: Yes, if your account is not in the C2DM system, it will not work.